# Sub queries in nz_migrate

Tags: netezza

I need to migrate data in netezza using below given sub query in where clause.

Sample:-  -sourcewhereclause "select * from abc..table1 where id in (select id from xyz..table2)"

Please let me know is that possible.

Answer (score 3):

As documented in nz_migarte help you can specify source where clause subquery filter, however, you need to provide only the where part of your query

> > -SourceWhereClause
>
> ```
> # Normally, nz_migrate is used to migrate over the entire contents of a
> # table -- all visible rows.  This option allows "you" to tack on a WHERE
> # clause to the data that gets selected ... allowing "you" to migrate a
> # subset of the table.  All the power (and responsibility) is put into your
> # hands.  Do wrap the clause in double quotes so it will be passed into the
> # script correctly.  Examples:
> #
> #    -SourceWhereClause  "customer_key = 2"
> #    -SourceWhereClause  "customer_key in (1,3,5)"
> #    -SourceWhereClause  "region_name = 'AMERICA' or region_key = 0"
> #    -SourceWhereClause  "order_date between '1998-01-01' and '1998-12-31'"
> #    -SourceWhereClause  "customer_num in (select cust_id from sales..delinquent_accounts)"
> ```

**Sample:-**

```
-sourcewhereclause "id in (select id from xyz..table2)"
```